# How to calculates shared edges length on a geopandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

I am working with geopandas, I have a voronoi shapefile, I need to perform certain calculations over the date. However, I am having problems on generating a quicker code: Let's say I have n elements, all of them polygons, I need to know the length of the edge the share (for the one they share):

[Voronoi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92vIk.png)

```
vorList = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data) #Serveral POLYGON elements

for index, block in vorList.iterrows():
    blockn=gpd.GeoDataFrame({'name':[0],'geometry':[block['geometry']]}) #If I convert on each iter the block to GeoDataFrame I cant perform the intersection
    vals=[]
    for blocki in block.NEIGHBORS.split(','):
        val=vorList.loc[vorList['NAME']==blocki,'geometry']
        neig=gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(val)
        intersect=blockn.geometry.intersection(neig.geometry)
        vals.append("%.2f"%intersect.length)
    vorList.at[index, "d"]= ",".join(vals) # Can I store arrays somehow?
```

The code works, but it takes long time, is there any way to optimize this process?

Comment: Can you edit the question to show a few rows of `vorList`?  Then maybe you could explain with reference to specific rows of that sample data exactly what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: If I understand your code snippet the inner loop assembles a list of edge lengths for block `index` by considering each neighbour and finding where it intersects block `index`.  Would it be faster to just look at the vertices of block `index` and calculate lengths between them without pulling up the neighbours?